# Why does map() mask the 'undefined value' error?

Tags: perl

I'm wondering why a call to `map` in the second snippet makes the 'undefined value' error gone?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x;
my @a = @{ $x }; # error: Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference
```

Compare to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x;
my @a = map $_, @{ $x }; # no error, @a is empty
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to the way that [map()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) does aliasing (it's essentially using a `for()` loop). What's happening is that the aref is being used in l-value context, and therefore is being [auto-vivified](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/) into existence.

In your former example, you're attempting to use the aref directly in r-value context, which is why it generates the error (because no auto-vivification happens).

You can simplify your test to use `for()`, and you'll get the same result as with `map()`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $x;

for (@{ $x }){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

...no output.

To visually see that `$x` was auto-vivified as an array reference, you can use the [ref()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function:

```
my $x;
my @a = map $_, @{ $x };

print ref $x;
```

Output:

```
ARRAY
```

Comment: also `ref($x)` will show that autovivification occurred.

Comment: @Сухой27 thanks! I didn't think of that at the time; answer updated