# Why does Perl's strict mode allow you to dereference a variable with an undefined value in this foreach context but not in an assignment context?

Tags: perl

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.18.0;
use strict;

# Part 1
my $undef = undef;
print "1 $undef\n";
foreach my $index (@$undef) {
  print "unreachable with no crash\n";
}
print "2 $undef\n";

# Part 2
my $undef = undef;
my @array = @$undef;
print "unreachable with crash\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1 
2 ARRAY(0x7faefa803ee8)
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /tmp/perlfile line 12.
```

Questions about Part 1:

1. Why does dereferencing `$undef` in the Part 1 change `$undef` to an arrayref to an empty array?
2. Are there other contexts (other than a foreach) where dereferencing `$undef` would change it in the same way? What is the terminology to describe the most generic such case?

Questions about Part 2:

3. Why does dereferencing `$undef` in the Part 2 fall afoul of `strict`?
4. Are there other contexts (other than assignment) where dereferencing `$undef` would fall afoul of `strict`. What is the terminology to describe the most generic such case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `for()` in Perl puts its operand into "l-value context", therefore the `$undef` is being [auto-vivified](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/) into existence as an array (reference) with zero elements (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246957/why-does-map-mask-the-undefined-value-error/40247420#40247420) relatively similar question/answer regarding l-value context).

3) Because you're trying to coercively assign an undefined value into something else in r-value context, and that's illegal under `strict` (nothing gets auto-vivified in this context, so you're not magically creating a variable from nothing like you would be in an l-value operation).

As far as question 2 and 4, there are several other context, too many to think of off the top of my head. For 2, `map()` comes to mind, or any other operation that treats the operand as an l-value.

Answer (score 2):

When you dereference an undefined variable in lvalue context, Perl will auto-vivify the reference and that which it references.

For example,

```
@$ref = qw( a b c );
```

means

```
@{ $ref //= [] } = qw( a b c );
```

---

When you dereference an undefined variable in rvalue context, Perl won't auto-vivify. Under strict refs, this is an error. Otherwise, undefined is stringified (with warning) to the empty string, which is used as symbolic reference.

For example,

```
no strict qw( refs ); my $ref; my @a = @$ref;
```

is equivalent to

```
no strict qw( refs ); my @a = @{""};
```

(Aside from the lack of warning for the latter.)

---

Lvalue context is provided to:

- The left-hand-side argument of assignments. (This is the "L" in "lvalue".)
- Arguments of sub and method calls (because of aliasing of elements of `@_`).
- Foreach's list (because of aliasing of `$_`).
- The operands of some named operators (e.g. `map` and `grep`, because of aliasing of `$_`).

Comment: You are a wizard.